# SNMP question regarding Traps with Cisco 3560

Tags: cisco, snmp

I have been requested by our development Team to create a lab enviroment for testing of various new software our company developes.

in the labhave a cisco switch configured to send out snmp v2 traps and i am looking for a way to generate a trap (of any kind) every 1 - 2 seconds .
the switch is configured properly and when using wireshark i can view the snmp traps its sending however in order for a trap to work i need an event to trigger it like a port shutdown or something similar .

**this leads me to the question how do i generate such a trap ?**

the reason why this must be a trap is because the port i am using to sniff the network is a monitor session port and being such .. it must recevie the traffic .

i tried playing with a CPU trap to maybe trigger some event every 2 seconds but no luck there.

any help or pointers will be much appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try

```
snmp-server enable traps config
```

and then go in and out of configure mode.  That is manually, but you can do it as often as you want.

Or, you can do

```
snmp-server enable traps event-manager
```

and write your own EEM script to do things, but that's not my area of expertise unfortunately.

Comment: Hello Aaron it seems you were right , thanks for pointing me in the right direction using EEM i managed to create what i needed it was fairly difficult but it works and all is well so Thanks . :)

Comment: You might want to add the EEM script you used here so others can refer to it - it sounds like it's a question that could be asked often.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a test trap command in IOS, you can create a loopback interface and do shut, no shut to generate trap. For automation, you can have expect do the same for you.